# Install turbolinks in HTML without JavaScript framework

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap-4, turbolinks

Just getting started with turbolinks and they claim it can be used without a client-side javascript framework, I made a bootstrap 4 template and tried installing it.

Downloaded the .js from repo file and included in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/turbolinks.js"></script>
```

And just before the closing body tag:

```
<script>
 Turbolinks.start()
</script>
```

Console debug don't give any errors, js is loaded but the whole page is loaded every time I visit a new link.

Tried to add `var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks")` in webserver but I get error.

**Server.js**

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks")

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "index.html" );
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000")
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English|Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e5f3028323.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/turbolinks.js"></script>

  <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="navbar sticky-top justify-content-between">
    <span></span>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">CW App</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-nav">
      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
    </button>
  </section>

  <div class="nav-bg"></div>

  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center cerca">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control form-control-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn-cerca my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="container" data-turbolinks-permanent>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="list-group list-button  mx-auto">
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/rulebook.png">Rulebook</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/factions.png">Factions</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/neutrals.png">Neutrals</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/maps.png">Maps</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/dice.png">Dice Roll</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/randomizer.png">Game Randomizer</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/doom.png">Doom & Ritual Track</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" onclick="window.location.href = './timer.html';">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/timer.png">Timer</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
          <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span><img class="menu-icon" src="img/icons-menu/music.png">Background Music</span>
            <span class="list-arrow">&rsaquo;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-native-v4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

  <script>
    Turbolinks.start()
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you testing your site on a webserver?

Comment: Can you show us what code you are using to initiate the navigation? We can't really help considering you've shown us barely anything to go on.

Comment: @InchHigh I updated the description, I'm not experienced with webserver but documentation is so scarse I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Artemis_ this still doesn't help, can you show your 'index.html' please. Also, if you're using ExpressJS, why don't you install TurboLinks using NPM ?

Comment: @InchHigh — Because TurboLinks is **client-side** code and installing it through npm would then probably lead to all sorts of messing around with webpack.

Comment: @InchHigh added index.html, I tried booth npm and classic <script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for TurboLinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) says:

> Turbolinks intercepts all clicks on `<a href>` links to the same domain.

… but your HTML **doesn't have any of those**.

You have some `<button>` elements, which I guess you might have some JavaScript to make them act like links, but TurboLinks isn't going to pick them up.

It does have a [mechanism for manually triggering TurboLinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#application-visits), but you'd be better off using real links instead of buttons and JavaScript.

Comment: That's right, I tried inserting <a href="/timer.html">timer</a> but it redirect to the same page (index.html) and console says "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." ...